# Box creation with given end coordinates

Tags: three.js

I can't figure out how to connect two coordinates(y axis doesn't change) with a box with given width and height, depth represents distance between coordinates.

How it should be done?

Comment: do you mean "coordinates" are points?

Comment: @prisoner849 yes, sorry if I was unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say, we have two points of THREE.Vector3().

To make a box of them, we need to find its width, height and depth.
Having two points, we can find width and depth

```
var width = Math.abs(point1.x - point2.x);
var depth = Math.abs(point1.z - point2.z);
```

You said that the height of the box depends on distance between those two points, we can find it this way

```
var height = point1.clone().sub(point2).length();
```

Then, we have to find a point, where we will put our box:

1. Find the point between our given points (average):

   `var center = point1.clone().add(point2).divideScalar(2);`
2. Create a new point for the center of our box:

   `var pointOfHeight = center.clone();`
3. Set the y-coordinate of the center by dividing the `height` by 2:

   `pointOfHeight.y = height / 2;`

Now we have everything to make the box:

```
var boxGeom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(width, height, depth);
var boxMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: "red", wireframe: true});
var box = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeom, boxMat);
```

And finally, we set the point of the box's origin:

```
box.position.copy(pointOfHeight);
```

In the end, we add the box to the scene:

```
scene.add(box);
```